# How to define a very large constant in an enumeration without a warning?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm working with the [CMCHTPC MediaFoundation headers](https://github.com/CMCHTPC/MediaFoundation), and they seem to work, but they give compiler warnings at several points that I'd like to get rid of.  The culprit in most cases seems to be with enums such as the following:

```
TMF_Plugin_Type = (
    MF_Plugin_Type_MFT = 0,
    MF_Plugin_Type_MediaSource = 1,
    MF_Plugin_Type_MFT_MatchOutputType = 2,
    MF_Plugin_Type_Other = DWORD(-1)
    );
```

No matter how that last value is defined, as `DWORD(-1)` or `DWORD($FFFFFFFF)` or simply as `$FFFFFFFF`, the compiler always replies:

> W1012 Constant expression violates subrange bounds

Is there any way to fix this definition without specifically suppressing that warning in the compiler?  (Note that `{$R-}` does not work; this turns off range checking at runtime, but not at compile time.)

Comment: I think the problem is that DWORD is a cardinal type which cannot have a negative value, so you cannot cast -1 to DWORD.

Comment: @J..., where do you get this restriction from?

Comment: @J..., and Integer can be negative.

Comment: @J...: Integer is a signed 32-bit, and therefore can have a negative value.

Comment: @UweRaabe Sorry, crossed wires.  I have no idea what I was thinking.  Casting to unsigned fails with a warning because the enum is natively an integer.  Casting to unsigned makes the value positive and larger than `MaxInt` - your solution is naturally correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can declare it just as -1 and give a {$Z4} to tell the compiler to use 4 bytes for this enum:

```
{$Z4}
type
  TMF_Plugin_Type = (
    MF_Plugin_Type_MFT = 0,
    MF_Plugin_Type_MediaSource = 1,
    MF_Plugin_Type_MFT_MatchOutputType = 2,
    MF_Plugin_Type_Other = -1);
```

It may as well work without the compiler directive. The docs say:

> To assign an ordinality to a value, follow its identifier with = constantExpression, where constantExpression is a constant expression that evaluates to an integer.

An Integer of value -1 is internally represented as 4 bytes. So either way should work.

**Update:** I rechecked and the compiler directive is indeed necessary (unless you set the similar option in the project options).

Comment: +1 Howewer if the compilation is done for x64 the enumerator is equal to -1. The following code `Caption:=vartostr(MF_Plugin_Type_Other);` will give different results if the code is compiled for x86 or x64. Compare the output

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Just try to add this line to somewhere like FormCreate and you shall see the different strings in the form caption if you compile for x86 and x64 platforms.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The enumerator will be 4 bytes in both cases. I am just saying that VarToStr will give different output strings: under x64 it will show `-1`, in x86 - `4294967295`.

Comment: @asd-tm I don't see where `VarToStr` comes into anything. What matters is the value passed to the external library.

Comment: @Uwe I don't think that the `$Z4` is necessary. I think it all works out just fine for `$Z1` and `$Z2` also. So, Mason should really stick to whatever is used currently by the library. I think it's important that he doesn't change this setting because it could break something else. Of course, it's probably `$Z4` already since that's the norm for a winapi C library. But you take my point.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have just checked. If the `{$Z4}` compiler directive is omitted then `SizeOf(MF_Plugin_Type_Other)` results in 1. So the value will be `$FF`, not `$FFFFFFFF`

Comment: @asd-tm You are incorrect. A simple program shows otherwise. This program outputs -1  `{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  {$Z1}
  TMF_Plugin_Type = (
    MF_Plugin_Type_Other = -1
  );

begin
  Writeln(Integer(MF_Plugin_Type_Other));
end.
`  And if you pass this value to an external function that receives an `int` then `-1` arrives.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have just rechecked it once again under my D XE5 compiling for both x64 and x86. SizeOf results in 1. `program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;
type

  TMF_Plugin_Type2 = (
    MF_Plugin_Type_MFT = 0,
    MF_Plugin_Type_MediaSource = 1,
    MF_Plugin_Type_MFT_MatchOutputType = 2,
    MF_Plugin_Type_Other = -1);

begin
 writeln(SizeOf(TMF_Plugin_Type2));
 readln;
end.
`

Comment: @asd-tm Yes that is true. I'm not disputing that. What output do you expect here: `{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  {$Z1}
  TMF_Plugin_Type = (
    MF_Plugin_Type_Other = -1
  );

procedure Foo(i: Integer);
begin
  Writeln(i);
end;

var
  FooProc: procedure(i: TMF_Plugin_Type);

begin
  FooProc := @Foo;
  FooProc(MF_Plugin_Type_Other);
end.`  Well, you'd expect `255` but in fact it is `-1`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am talking about the size, not the value. If the {$Z4} is skipped then the compiler generates an enumerator with the size of 1 byte. That means that it can not represent $ffffffff except through the cast DWORD(MF_Plugin_Type_Other), can it? So we need to keep in mind ever to cast the constant to DWORD when accessing it.

Comment: @asd-tm You might well be talking about the size. We can all agree that with `$Z1` then the size is one. I'm talking about something else though. If you want to talk about that then that's fine. I'm talking about the value passed to the external library. You must appreciate that this is an interop type and the only thing that matters is that it is the right size, and the right value gets passed. Now, the right size is whatever the size is on the interop side. The enum size in the Delphi code should match. If the size is 4, use `$Z4`, if the size is 2 use `$Z2`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Bingo! That is what I ment. We have to use compiler directive setting the enumerator size explicitly. And we should not skip it relying on the compiler. Otherwise the compiler will set its size automatically. Try, for example, to set MF_Plugin_Type_MFT_MatchOutputType = 257. The compiler will set the size to 2 bytes. So the later edits to the enumerator type and adding other constants might affect the behaviour of the code.

Comment: @asd-tm No, you've missed my point entirely. Never mind. I'm not going to repeat myself.

Comment: @Uwe regarding your edit, enum size is unrelated to the issue here. You'll get no compiler warnings and a value of -1 for all enum sizes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I see that assigning that enum value will always set the correct value. My concern is when such an enum is part of a record structure. In that case the type should be of proper size as well. I was under the impression that Mason was especially interested in making this value equal to $FFFFFFFF. The weird fact is that Delphi stores those enums as unsigned values of the requested size, but interprets any constant expression as Integer. On the other hand: nobody is perfect.

Comment: @Uwe My point is that the issue of enum size and the issue of the compiler warnings are distinct. I'm quite sure that `$Z4` is the correct setting since this is interop with a C Windows API. And they use 4 byte enums. I am also sure that the enum size is already specified in the code that Mason is using. If it were not then the wrapper would not be correct. So I think it is somewhat misleading to conflate the two issues and there is no need for `$Z4` to be restated on every enum that happens to have a `-1` value. To me that would make the code very misleading indeed.

Comment: @Uwe and take a look at the actual code that Mason refers to. It is here: https://github.com/CMCHTPC/MediaFoundation/blob/8ddddf99f7d1ec546d1ae284f1937f06ff7b623d/Units/CMC.MFObjects.pas  Note that it already has `$Z4` as I predicted. I think your answer would be cleaner if it did not conflate the two distinct issues. I hope Mason is still here.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options so far as I can tell.

1. Remove the `DWORD` cast and replace `DWORD(-1)` with `-1`, as described in Uwe's answer.
2. Suppress this particular compiler warning. You can do that in code with `{$WARN BOUNDS_ERROR OFF}`.

The downside of option 1 is that you have to find every such declaration and change it. It means making wholesale changes to a third party library. If you wish to accept a new version of that library then you have to re-apply these changes. For some libraries this might be problematic.

So in my view suppressing the warnings may well be the cleaner approach. You can put the suppressing directive in an include file, or at the head of the unit. This means that the changes you make to the third party code are narrower in scope.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can see how `TColor` and `TColorRec` are declared in `System.UITypes` and use the experience of Embarcadero declaring something like this:

```
  TMF_Plugin_Type = $0 .. $FFFFFFFF;

  TMF_Plugin_Type_Rec = record
  const
    MF_Plugin_Type_MFT = 0;
    MF_Plugin_Type_MediaSource = 1;
    MF_Plugin_Type_MFT_MatchOutputType = 2;
    MF_Plugin_Type_Other = TMF_Plugin_Type($FFFFFFFF);
  end;
```

Comment: The problem is, this would break all existing code that expects to be able to use these enums without prefixing it with the type name and a dot.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I do not see any problem here as there is refactoring engine that can rename everything in three clicks.

Comment: Have you ever been able to actually make that thing work? o_0

Comment: @MasonWheeler Yes! Why? :-))

Comment: @MasonWheeler Select  the variable/constant name in the code and press Shift+Ctrl+E

Comment: Rename doesn't work on real world code bases in my experience.

Comment: Rename refactoring works pretty well, IME, and I use it a lot. The only problem I sometimes have are if some parts of code are managed by `$IFDEF`s, or with assembler.

Comment: @Rudy That's nice for you. Try on a big project.

Comment: I think it is nice for me too. <g>